# Determining solutions for convergence of formal power series

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, formal-power-series

Consider the following power series
$$
S = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n x^n
$$
where $(a_0, a_1, \dotsc)$ is a sequence of complex numbers and $x$ is a complex variable.

If, say, for all $n$ the coefficients $a_n$ satisfy $\lvert a_n \rvert < C$ for some positive real number $C$, then the series $S$ converges for $\lvert x \rvert < 1$. However, if one requires only that $\lvert a_n \rvert < 2^n C$, then for $\lvert x \rvert < \frac12$ the series still converges, but this second constraint is much more relaxed.

I feel that I am missing the necessary (functional?) analysis background to understand the interplay between choosing a fixed $x$ and determining the condition on the sequences $(a_0, a_1, \dotsc)$ for which the series $S$ converges.

More precisely, I would like to determine the (space of?) sequences $(a_0, a_1, \dotsc)$, for which $S$ converges as soon as $0 < \lvert x \rvert < \epsilon \ll 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the basic theory on power series.
Let $A:=(a_n)_{n\geq 0} \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a fixed sequence for which there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that the series 
$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n \tag{1}
$$ converge for $|z|<\varepsilon$. This means that the series $(1)$ has positive [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence). In particular, for the radius $r = \frac{1}{\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}} \geq \varepsilon>0$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) for the application of the root test to derive the formula for the radius of convergence).

Thus, the set of all sequences $A$ for which the series $(1)$ converge for some $\varepsilon$ is precisely the set of all sequences $(a_n)$ for which the limit
$$
\tag{2} \limsup |a_n|^{1/n} < \infty.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful. Does this set (of sequences) have any additional structure? Is it a Banach or a Hilbert space?

Comment: @Earthliŋ, one may define addition (even multiplication) on the space of sequences satisfying $(2)$ making it a linear space (even an algebra). Indeed, if $(a_n)$ satisfies $(2)$, then there exists a constant $K>0$ such that $|a_n| \leq K^n$ for all $n$. Using this it's easy to see that coordinate-wise addition, multiplication and multiplication by scalar of two sequences satisfying $(2)$ preserves the condition.

Comment: @Earthliŋ, to make the space of sequences satisfying $(2)$ (which we now know that is a linear space) into a Hilbert space, take a sequence which grows much faster than any exponential, for instance $n!$, and for $a:=(a_n)$ and $b:=(b_n)$ both satisfying $(2)$ define
$$
\tag{A} \langle  a,b \rangle := \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n \overline{b_n}}{n!}.
$$
The series converges as $|a_n b_n|$ is bounded above by a sequence $K^n$ for some fixed (possibly very large) constant $K>0$, and $n!$ grows much faster than $K^n$ for any $K>0$. Thus $(A)$ defines a scalar product.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I guess there is also the adic topology on the space of all sequences — do you know how this compares to the topology induced by the inner product?

Comment: @Earthliŋ, I'm not sure about the adic topology you refer to and which induced topology will it compare to. Changing the inner product will change the topology (the product defined above is not unique of course), so it's hard to specify which inner product will be the natural one.

Comment: I was referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Topological_structure which makes the (countably infinite-dimensional) space of formal power series into a topological vector space. The set of sequences satisfying $(2)$ is a vector subspace and can thus be endowed with the subspace topology. I was wondering how this topology compares to the topology coming from an inner product such as $(A)$...

Comment: @Earthliŋ, that would need some thought. In the Wikipedia article of your comment, there are $3$ different topologies one may use for the sequences discussed (I understand you're interested in the second one in the Wikipedia list). However, I don't see a quick way at the moment to tell how that compares to the topology induced by the inner product $(A)$, except a kind of brute force approach of checking by hand.